# Parsing JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey. I am trying to parse some JSON into HTML using jQuery. I’ve checked to see if my API request is working, and it is.

I think it gets stuck when appending the HTML.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?apikey=MY_API_KEY&location=ip:94.228.36.39', function(data) {
        $('.json').html('<p>' + data.location + '</p>' + '<p>' + data.uri + '</p>');
    });
});
```

`getJson` returns loads of data in the following format, but I can’t seem to parse it to HTML.

```
{
    "resultsPage": {
        "totalEntries": 99,
        "page": 1,
        "results": {
            "event": [
                {
                    "type":"Concert",
                    "location": {
                        "city":"Huddersfield, UK"
                        ,"lng":-1.78333,
                        "lat":53.65},
                    "popularity":0.0,
                    "status":"ok",
                    "uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/concerts\/4993456-barbirolli-quartet-at-st-pauls-hall?utm_source=2251&utm_medium=partner",
                    "venue":{
                        "uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/venues\/156338-st-pauls-hall?utm_source=2251&utm_medium=partner",
                        "lng":-1.78333,
                        "displayName":"St. Paul's Hall",
                        "id":156338,
                        "metroArea": etc......
```

Comment: Have you thrown it at http://www.jsonlint.com/ ? Also, have you looked at the Firebug error console and network tab?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the response doesn't have the properties `location` or `uri`.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $.getJSON('http://api.songkick.com/api/3.0/events.json?...', function(data) {
        // only guessing based on the information provided
        var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
        for (var i = 0, l = events.length; i < l; i++) {
            $('.json').append('<p>' + events[i].location.city + '</p>'
                + '<p>' + events[i].uri + '</p>');
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: See my updated answer for an example that shows Ryan's example should work

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I can see, is, that the structure of your JSON is different from what you try to evaluate. It's much deeper nested. So instead of `data.location` you will need something like `data.resultsPage.results.event[0].location`.

That means, most probably you are just missing a loop over `data.resultsPage.results.event` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON object you gave as an example is several levels deep. To get to the location you will have to nest inside -

```
var events = data['resultsPage']['results']['event'];
//Actually an array of events
var location = events[0]['location'];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Added Ryan's function to show you it does work with the JSON given so something else is missing - here is the plain JS version

```
<div id="eventDiv"></div>
<script>
var data = {  
  "resultsPage": {    
    "totalEntries": 99,    
    "page": 1,    
    "results": {
      "event": [
        {"type":"Concert",
           "location": { 
             "city":"Huddersfield, UK","lng":-1.78333,"lat":53.65
           },
           "popularity":0.0,
           "status":"ok",
           "uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/concerts\/4993456-barbirolli-quartet-at-st-pauls-hall?utm_source=2251&utm_medium=partner",
           "venue": {
             "uri":"http:\/\/www.songkick.com\/venues\/156338-st-pauls-hall?utm_source=2251&utm_medium=partner",
             "lng":-1.78333,
             "displayName":"St. Paul's Hall",
             "id":156338
          }
        } 
      ]
    }
  }
}
window.onload=function() {
  var events = data.resultsPage.results.event;
  for (var i = 0, l = events.length; i < l; i++) {
    document.getElementById('eventDiv').innerHTML='<p>' + events[i].location.city + '</p><p>' + events[i].uri + '</p>';
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here.  The problem was with the syntax of the nested data.

I changed:

```
+ events.location.city +
```

To:

```
+ events.location['city'] +
```

For each of the required fields that were nested.  For un-nested, just drop the brackets:

```
+ events.uri +
```